# Linux Operating System for absolute beginner

Tags: linux

I am absolutely new in Linux. So,what distribution/version should a beginner like me install to get started with?I had Mint in mind , but I would like to know from experts.So please do let me know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you're a beginner, I'd just install one and start learning about the basics, i.e. directory structure, services, shell programming, development tools, etc. Mint sounds like a nice option to go with. Once you know enough what you want and like you could be moving to another one. I don't think there is an "expert" who spent all his/her life with a single distro.

Comment: Thanks Baris.So Mint would provide me with both  a GUI and a command line interface?Because I am really interested to work with the cli mode in Linux.